# Remove Windows 10 User Account Picture Logon Screen

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I just installed Windows 10 Pro Creators Update Version 1703 Build 15063.0. I want to remove user account picture (big circle) on the login screen.
I tried deleting pictures from:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures
C:\Users\Public\AccountPictures
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures
```

Also tried deleting SID folder. I just can't remember how I did it in anniversary update.

Comment: I deleted those folders as you mention. But that only remove image from "Settings > Account > your info"  only. The login image remains.

Comment: That is the same issue i am facing

Comment: Something associate with this file `C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Logon.dll`.

Comment: I wish this had an answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Open This PC, click on View menu and tick the Hidden Items checkbox. This enables you to see hidden files and folders.

Follow this path to find your account pictures:
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Account Pictures

Comment: OP mentioned your folder path in his post.